# PHP can use $c = $a_$b["$z"]?

Tags: php

I created a array_common.php to save my array.
because these array always use.

```
function show_common($value,$type){
    $array_common =  substr(dirname(__FILE__),0,-10)."config/array_common.php";

    include "$array_common";    
    $show = $arr_.$type["$value"];
    return $show;

}
```

I include array_common.php
so I got the these array value.
array_common.php content

```
$arr_come_from=array(
    "1"=>"Google",
    "2"=>"facebook",
    "3"=>"yahoo",
    "4"=>"twitter",
    "99"=>"other"
);
$arr_gender=array(
    "1"=>"Male",
    "2"=>"Female"
);
```

I created this function and I hope use this to show array content

```
 show_common(2,come_from);  //echo facebook
 show_common(1,gender);  //echo Male 
 show_common(2,gender);  //echo Female
```

but php Notice: `Notice: Undefined variable: arr_ in.........`

maybe this code problem?

```
$show = $arr_.$type["$value"];
```

any suggest?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.  You've made a good start, but we really should have the full error message, including location and stack trace (if any).  Also, include all of the pertinent code; the 3-line function you list is not a complete function.

Comment: P.S. You can just do `include $array_common;`.

Comment: Rocket Hazmat,thanks your suggest. but this function is a smarty plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `{}` [Complex (curly) syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex) to build the name of the variable you are trying to access:

```
$show = ${'arr_'.$type}["$value"];
```

Comment: I got it. Thanks so much !